# How to add user picture to search result when using Search API

Tags: views, search

Am using the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module on my site.

I have indexed users on my site and added the corresponding view to display the search result.

My question  is how do i add the user picture. This does not appear to be included in the views field by default.